# Selecting from relation based on other relation

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

Given a relation A(a,b,c), and a relation B(a,d,e), using projection to isolate 'a' in 'B' like so 'B_=projection_{a}(B)', is there a way to exclude all tupples in 'A', that does not have an 'a' in common with 'B'?

Note that i'm only using relational algebra, and not the extended version.

Comment: Hi. If you got all the tuples with a's in common then you would want the tuples left when you removed those from the value of A. Re in common read about join(s) & re removing read about difference. You already know about projection to drop attributes. Please show what parts 

and/or cases you are able to do & ask your question about the simplest 

case you can. PS There are many RAs even with different notions of 'relation' so in a RA question summarize your operator names & how they work and/or give your textbook name & edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to exclude all tupples in 'A', that does not have an 'a' in common with 'B'?

That's a double negative: "exclude ... not ...". Let's turn it into a positive:

"Show all tuples in `A` that *do* have an `a` in common with `B`."

That is, you want a subset of the tuples. It's important here that `a` is the only attribute name in common between the two relations. Then here's a start with [Natural Join](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Natural_join_(%E2%8B%88)).

```
A ⋈ B
```

That will produce a result with all attributes `{a, b, c, d, e}`. Not yet what you want, so you're on the right track with a projection. I'll use Codd's original operator (`π`). There's two ways; these are equivalent:

```
A ⋈ (π{a}( B ))            // take just {a} from B
π{a, b, c}( A ⋈ B )        // take {a, b, c} from the result of Join
```

It's a commonly-needed operation, so there's also a shorthand amongst the "extended" set of operators, to avoid that projection, called [(left) SemiJoin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_(%E2%8B%89)(%E2%8B%8A))

```
A ⋉ B
```

Also called 'Matching'.